# Issue with dropdown overlay using CSS

Tags: css

I am unable to fix the following issues:

1. Notice the drop down menus 'Company branches' & 'Fields of Business', when expanded, it gets hidden behind the lower section. What I wish for is to bring it to the top.
2. When viewed on mobile, the header logo + text is not fitting in and the logo is going out of the view. What's the best way to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you create a code snippet and share here?

Comment: Seems like a little combination of things. OP might had to paste entire website here. But, creating a cut-down version of the problem might help.

Answer (score 1):

For 2nd Issue use this

```
.main-header .hero-header .inner-hero-header {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 10;
bottom: 0;
}
```

.inner-hero-header class position is 'absolute' so, you change the position as 'relative'

Answer (score 0):

1: The first issue with the **hidden select** field can be handled via z-index. Or switching the DOM Order. But in this case it might be easier to include a simple **z-index** on the fields.

```
.form-group.location-form {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This does the job ... well kinda.
The field is larger than its container, and somewhere up the DOM-Tree **overflow hidden** is specified. On the **.hero-header** to be exact.
I don't know why it's needed. But I suggest removing it. *(style.css:1560)*

2: The Headline Logo issue is caused by **position: absolute** in combination with bottom: 0;
It looks like that this is not really needed.
Changing it to **position: relative;** does the trick.
This way, the **element can grow**, when the text in the headline needs more height, without overlapping other elements.

```
.main-header .hero-header .inner-hero-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Btw: the bottom and left values can be omitted here.

Comment: Thanks Type-Style, you saved my day :) Regards,

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept if you can! ;-) You're welcome.